# How would I translate the two morphemes 基腐 together?

Tags: translation, slang

I am trying to translate this in the context of 基腐头条, I understand the meaning - the 基 is referring to gay (men) and 腐 is a shortened version of 腐女, 'rotten girls' or 'females interested in gay culture.' It is just hard to find a succinct translation that provides all of this cultural context... Suggestions?

Comment: Just one thing I am sure: although 腐 is often referred to 腐女, it doesn't have to be, because there're also 腐男—not gay (at least they claim so), but "males interested in gay culture".

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe an established, succinct English translation exists yet. I would try to translate as 'BL & Fandom' or 'BL & Fans'.

For 基, I would prefer to use words like Boy Love/[Yaoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaoi) over gay/homosexual to convey the romantic and fantasized view of male homosexual in 腐 culture. I also couldn't find any better translation for 腐女 than BL fans. Hence 基腐 can be shorted to 'BL & Fans'.

Comment: My understanding of 基 here is not as BL, but rather as referring to gay men (like 面基: meet your gay [friends]). And in the context of this particular  基腐头条 news service (on WeChat), they don't discuss BL per se, they are discussing contemporary 'gay' news from China and abroad. Hence my difficulty translating.

Comment: @TylerGleason Hmmm that sounds like a very ambiguous usage if not completely inaccurate, at least to me. But if that's the case, wpt's answer is worth considering.

Comment: @TylerGleason the problem is, even those friends we (native speakers) shall meet are not gay (more even, it's not confined to "men"!), we can also use 面基 for some joking effect. That new word has never got a rigorous definition. It seems young people would use 基 very unconsciously, so in fact 基 doesn't necessarily mean "gay"—the word 基友 is definitely not "gay friend"!

Comment: @Stan broadly speaking, I totally get the usage of 基 to mean a (male) friend. But in this context, it is referring to gay males. I was just using 面基to clarify that point - a poor example perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that came to my mind was `fangays`. Maybe its my gaming background, but it could be appropriately slang.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article in Wikipedia called [fag-hag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fag_hag) that has a number of phrases you might consider. Apologies if this reference is offensive; sounds quite insulting to me too, but that's what the Wikipedia article is titled.